# Querying on datetimes in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, gql

I am not able to query on datetime fields in google app engine. I am trying to run the following query -

```
SELECT * FROM Email WHERE cmp_id='52d836ed1057c341b800013a' AND pushed_to_crm=TRUE AND ss_time >= DATETIME('2014-01-17 00:00:00')
```

I am sure that this should return some rows - I mean that there is data in the database that should be returned.

But I get an error in running this query -

```
Learn more about GQL syntax.
no matching index found.
The suggested index for this query is:
- kind: Email
  properties:
  - name: cmp_id
  - name: pushed_to_crm
  - name: ss_time
```

The field `ss_time` is `db.DateTimeProperty()`. Is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is quite clear. You have to add index for your Email entity with the following attributes: `cmp_id`, `pushed_to_crm` and `ss_time`.

You can do that by adding the following to your `index.yaml`:

```
- kind: Email
  properties:
  - name: cmp_id
  - name: pushed_to_crm
  - name: ss_time
```

Comment: I created the indexes and deployed. I can see that the indexes has been created but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Oh! I got it... you have to create indexes for each query. So if a query on the Email entity uses two properties, you need to create an index for those two properties. If again, you have a query on Email entity for two different properties, you need to create an index for those two properties separately.